# How can I determine the origin of a downloaded file?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, internet, file-download

Is there a way to determine what the original source or link was for a previously downloaded file, other than using the browser's download history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: NO.

However, sites often provide a checksum such as SHA1 or MD5 to help you verify a successful download.

You can create the checksum and then Google it. For example, I have a file:

`VMware-workstation-full-7.1.0-261024.exe`

which has SHA1 checksum:

`5512cb520fc91b8c4ee9b0d6f80d1cfecb0fe50f`

When I Google the checksum I get the VMware Workstation 7.1 for Windows Download Page as the #1 result.

So while I can't be sure that I downloaded my copy of this file from this particular site, I can be sure that it is the same file.

Comment: this was helpful ... but what about sites that do not provide such information .... can i google for checksums's that i " calculated my self " ????

Comment: Yes, you can calculate the checksums yourself. In Ubuntu you can use the command line utilities `sha1sum` and `md5sum`. There are also Windows equivalents as well as GUI apps. Unfortunately, if the sites don't publish checksums then you can't use this method.

Answer (score 2):

In OS X, it is stored in the file's metadata (right-click > Get Info).
I don't have an active Windows install to check, but it may be recorded in the same way by the OS there, too (right-click > Properties). I'm not sure about that, but you could give it a try.

Comment: I just checked on Windows 7 - it will tell you if the file was downloaded from the internet, but not the URL it was downloaded from.

Comment: Dang... I wonder if it's still embedded, but you'll need a separate program to see it.

Comment: See this answer: http://superuser.com/a/695529/46326 for a description of where it is stored in Windows NTFS filesystems